# WPF: How to make Visual Studio stop debugging on close

Tags: wpf, debugging

We have a WPF Prism application. When we close the application from the kill button or our exit routine I want the debugging session to automatically close. I don't want to have to click the stop button in the IDE every time. Where is the setting?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to close the app? Sounds like something is keeping your app from shutdown...

Comment: Application.Current.Shutdown();

The application is shutting down. The debugger is not. I just discovered that IIS Express that hosts our Service layer is still running. When I shut it down explicitly the debugger stops. However the debugger does not appear to be attached to it so I don't know why it is having that effect.